# Proper implementation of Sequence Protocol in a Class

Tags: swift, protocols, signal-processing

I have been working on learning something about the Accelerate framework and am writing a Vector class to go along with my learning experience.  I decided I needed to implement the Sequence protocol and after several false starts and much searching for relevant information to my problem finally came up with a solution that seems to work.  Not sure if my solution is proper or not and would like comment if there are better ways to do this.  Current code is a bit long but not super long so I will post it here.

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

public class Vdsp{
public class VectorD: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    var vindex = 0

    public func makeIterator() -> Double? {
        return next()
    }
    public func next() -> Double? {
        let nextIndex = self.vindex * self.s + self.o
        guard self.vindex < self.l  && nextIndex < self.count
            else {
                self.vindex = 0
                return nil
        }
        self.vindex += 1
        return self.data[nextIndex]
    }

    public let count : Int
    fileprivate var l: Int
    fileprivate var o: Int
    fileprivate var s: Int
    public var length : Int {
        get {
            return self.l
        }
        set (value){
            let l = (value - 1) * self.s + self.o
            if l < 0 || l >= self.count {
                preconditionFailure("length exceeds vector boundary")
            }
            self.l = value
        }
    }
    public var stride : Int {
        get {
            return self.s
        }
        set (value){
            let l = (self.l - 1) * value + self.o
            if l < 0 || l >= self.count {
                preconditionFailure("stride will cause vector to exceed vector boundary")
            }
            self.s = value
        }
    }
    public var offset : Int {
        get {
            return self.o
        }
        set (value){
            let l = (self.l - 1) * self.s + value
            if l < 0 || l >= self.count {
                preconditionFailure("stride will cause vector to exceed vector boundary")
            }
            self.o = value
        }
    }
    // length * stride + offset >= 0 and <= count
    public var data : Array<Double>
    public init(length: Int){
        self.count = length
        self.l = length
        self.s = 1
        self.o = 0
        data = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: count)
    }
    // MARK: - Utility functions
    public var empty : VectorD { // Create a new vector unit stride, zero offset
        get{
            return VectorD(length: length)
        }
    }
    public func display(decimals: Int) -> String {
        let fmt = String("%0." + String(decimals) + "f\n")
        var aString = ""
        for i in 0..<length {
            aString += String(format: fmt!, self.data[offset + i * stride])
        }
        return aString
    }
    // MARK: - Subscripts and Operators
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Double {
        get {
            if index > length {
                preconditionFailure("index \(index) out of bounds")
            } else {
                return data[self.offset + index * self.stride]
            }
        }
        set(newValue) {
            if index > self.length {
                preconditionFailure("index \(index) out of bounds")
            } else {
                self.data[self.offset + index * self.stride] = newValue
            }
        }
    }


    public static func + (left: VectorD, right: VectorD) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.add(left, right)
    }
    public static func + (left: Double, right: VectorD) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.add(left, right)
    }
    public static func + (left: VectorD, right: Double) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.add(right, left)
    }
    public static func * (left: VectorD, right: VectorD) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.mul(left, right)
    }
    public static func * (left: Double, right: VectorD) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.mul(left, right)
    }
    public static func * (left: VectorD, right: Double) -> VectorD {
        return Vdsp.mul(right, left)
    }

    // MARK: - vDSP routines as methods of VectorD
    public func fill(value: Double){
        var v = value
        vDSP_vfillD(&v, &data + offset, stride, vDSP_Length(length))
    }
    public func ramp(start: Double, increment: Double){
        var s = start
        var i = increment
        vDSP_vrampD(&s, &i, &data + offset, stride, vDSP_Length(length))
    }
    public var sumval : Double {
        get {
            var s : Double = 0.0
            vDSP_sveD(&data + offset, stride, &s, vDSP_Length(length))
            return s
        }
    }

}
// MARK: - vDSP routines as class functions of Vdsp
public static func add(_ v1: VectorD, _ v2: VectorD) -> VectorD {
    let v3 = v1.empty
    vDSP_vaddD( &v1.data + v1.offset, v1.stride, &v2.data + v2.offset , v2.stride, &v3.data, 1, vDSP_Length(v3.length))
    return v3
}
public static func add(_ s: Double, _ v: VectorD) -> VectorD {
    var sdta = s
    let r = v.empty
    vDSP_vsaddD( &v.data + v.offset, v.stride, &sdta, &r.data, 1, vDSP_Length(v.length))
    return r
}

public static func mul(_ v1: VectorD, _ v2: VectorD) -> VectorD {
    let v3 = v1.empty
    vDSP_vmulD( &v1.data + v1.offset, v1.stride, &v2.data + v2.offset, v2.stride, &v3.data, 1, vDSP_Length(v3.length))
    return v3
}
public static func mul(_ s: Double, _ v: VectorD) -> VectorD {
    var sdta = s
    let r = v.empty
    vDSP_vsmulD( &v.data + v.offset, v.stride, &sdta, &r.data, 1, vDSP_Length(v.length))
    return r
   }
}
```

I am exercising this with

```
//: Playground for Accelerate

import UIKit

let V = Vdsp.VectorD(length: 10);V.ramp(start: 0.1, increment: 0.2)
print("Vector V after ramp(0.1,0.2)");print(V.display(decimals: 3))
V.length = 4
V.stride = 2
V.offset = 1
print("Vector V after attribute modification")
print(V.display(decimals: 3))
let Q = V.empty
Q.ramp(start: 1.0, increment: 1.0)
print("Vector Q after ramp(1.0,1.0)");print(Q.display(decimals: 3))
print("V * Q"); var R = V * Q
for i in 0..<V.length {
   print("\(V[i]) * \(Q[i]) =  \(R[i])")
}
R = V + Q; print("V + Q = R")
for i in 0..<V.length {
    print("\(V[i]) + \(Q[i]) =  \(R[i])")
}
print("\n")
for item in V.data {
   print(item)
}
print("\n")
for item in V {
   print(item)
}

print("\n")
V.offset = 3
for item in V {
   print(item)
}
```

and I seem to get the proper output. The Sequence protocol is in the first few lines of the VectorD class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of the `Sequence` protocol is not correct.

First, your `makeIterator()` method is not used at all because it has the wrong signature,
it does not return an `Iterator`. (You can remove that function from your code without changing anything.) Iterating over the vector elements works
because there is a default implementation of `makeIterator()` for all
iterators which are declared to conform to `Sequence`.

Second, your `next()` method uses an instance variable `vindex` 
which is reset to zero after reaching the end of the iteration.
In other words, it is assumed that *all* elements are retrieved before
iterating the same vector again. This gives the unexpected output:

```
let V = Vdsp.VectorD(length: 10)
V.ramp(start: 1.0, increment: 1.0)

print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [9.0, 10.0]
print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Here is a possible implementation of the `Sequence` protocol:

```
public class VectorD: Sequence {

    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Double> {
        var vindex = 0
        return AnyIterator {
            let nextIndex = vindex * self.s + self.o
            guard vindex < self.l  && nextIndex < self.count else {
                return nil
            }
            vindex += 1
            return self.data[nextIndex]
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Note that `vindex` is now a local variable of `makeIterator()`
and captured by the closure. Calling `makeIterator()` again
will start from the beginning even if the previous iteration did
not retrieve all elements:

```
print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
print(Array(V.prefix(4))) // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Another possible implementation would be

```
public class VectorD: Sequence {

    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<Double> {
        let upperBound = Swift.min(count, o + l * s)
        let it = Swift.stride(from: o, to: upperBound, by: s)
            .lazy.map { self.data[$0] }.makeIterator()
        return AnyIterator(it)
    }

    // ...
}
```

using the `stride()` method from the Swift standard
library.